# Render JSON based on the Environment for all models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, activerecord

I am using a helper method to make my json pretty:

```
def make_pretty_json(json_object)
 if (Rails.env == "development" || Rails.env == "staging")
   JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(json_object))
 else
   json_object
 end
end
```

I then call the helper in my controller:

```
@jobs = make_pretty_json(@jobs)
```

and do a

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { 
    render json: @jobs
  }
```

I have to do this manually for all my models. Is there a way to do this globally so I get Pretty Indented JSON only in certain ENVIRONMENTS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a prettier view of your json just for yourself, i recommend the JsonView plugin for chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc

Comment: Hey Karl, thanks for the answer. The front end dev is done via flash and they are tracing the output there so this won't help me!